Get installed package names from Conda
Problem
When setting up repos, I often get lists of many packages from someone piping conda list into a requirements.txt file. Given I have different pinned packages (e.g. python, cuda), I frequently need to install the same packages without the accompanying specified versions. Conda does a great job of finding out what package versions are compatible with your pinned packages if you just hand it a list of package names. Imagine someone has a conda env set up on our shared machine and I want to build my own environment off of theirs. Is there a solution1 (perhaps a mamba/conda property used to build these the conda list output) that I can utilize to just get a list of the packages to install sans their version and channel etc?
Current
Truncated conda list output example:
...
libstdcxx-ng              13.1.0               hfd8a6a1_0    conda-forge
libuuid                   2.38.1               h0b41bf4_0    conda-forge
libxml2                   2.11.4               h0d562d8_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.13               hd590300_5    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.4                hcb278e6_0    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10              h516909a_1000    conda-forge
...
pluggy                    1.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.9.5           py311h2582759_0    conda-forge
...

Desired Output:
... libstdcxx-ng libuuid libxml2 libzlib lz4-c lzo ... pluggy psutil ...

1 Ideally this won't involve copy-paste or regex.

Try using awk maybe? For Linux/macOS only:
You can try to pipe the conda list output into awk to extract only the first desired column:
conda list | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +4

This should work, otherwise:
conda list | grep -v '#' | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +4

Additionally, if you want the output in the same line then you can replace the \n with ' '
conda list | grep -v '#' | awk '{print $1}' | tail -n +4 | tr '\n' ' '

Expected Output:

libstdcxx-ng libuuid libxml2 libzlib lz4-c lzo pluggy psutil


Solution
A revised version of @NamanMadharia's post to avoid headers and simplify it a bit:
conda list | awk '!/^#/ && NF {print $1}' | xargs
This doesn't use a conda property, but the conda list output comes in columns and can be manipulated with the above command easily enough.
Breakdown:

conda list (OP already describes what this one does)
| is the 'pipe' command and sends the output of a previous command as input for the next.
awk "is a utility that enables a programmer to write tiny programs [and] is mostly used for pattern scanning and processing."[1]
!/^#/ ignores any comment lines in the output eg the column headers.
&& NF makes sure the line has at least one field of content, ignoring empty lines.
{print $1} prints the content of the line's first column.
xargs prints the outputs of the previous command (which is run on every line) as one line seperated by spaces.

